# Newsletter sign up tokens on Donation Form Error

Tags: wordpress, email, tokens, forms

We are having an issue passing a check-sum from a donation and membership sign up form along with a token to sign up to join a mailing list.  We're implementing CiviCRM on a WordPress platform. The newsletter mailing list sign up token is not recognized by the system.

Comment: can you provide some examples of the urls that are going out? or is it purely that the token isn't being replaced with contact data? examples will help people help you i think

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by 'passing a checksum from a donation form'. do you mean as part of the receipt, or via a scheduled reminder, or something else

Answer (score 1):

You might compare your checksum links against the examples in [this post](https://aghstrategies.com/content/how-create-one-click-personalized-links-civicrm-emails).

As for your mailing list signup form, I'm not sure what you mean by "not recognized by the system".  Is the token not transforming when sent, or is the link just not working?